# Loading web-page with moment in electron

Tags: momentjs, electron

I am trying to load a web-page in an electron application, it is my first try to use electron so I am not familiar with it at all. The app is really simple:

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
app.on('ready', function() {
   browser = new BrowserWindow({
       width:800,
       height:600
    })
    browser.loadUrl('http://example.com/page.aspx');
});
```

The page is using moment (it is a call to moment.langData(...) that fails), but gets the error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined.

My web page works in Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Any ideas on how to make this work, if possible I would like to avoid changes in the web-page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating the BrowserWindow with the flag 'node-integration' set to false, seems to do it.

```
browser = new BrowserWindow({
    'node-integration': false,
    width:800,
    height:600,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.momemt = require(__dirname+'/js/moment.js');
</script>
```

This will work as moment has node support.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was inspired by  @jabocop answer that wasn't working for me pehaprs due to version or the fact that I use angular.

I use

```
let browser =  new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({show: false, 
                                                 webPreferences:{nodeIntegration: false}});
```